# Apache undoes my change to User in httpd.conf

Tags: apache-http-server, mamp

In order to make my MAMP environment be more like my work environment, I'm trying to change Apache to run under `_www` rather than `<myusername>`.

I located the appropriate `httpd.conf` file in the folder `/Applications/MAMP/Library/conf/apache`, but when I save my changes and restart MAMP, I find that it has changed the `User` directive back to `<myusername>`.

So either Apache or some aspect of MAMP is not allowing me to change this directive. Does anyone know which program is causing the rewrite and how to circumvent this problem?

The reason I'm trying to do this really is that I don't want *PHP* to run as `<myusername>` and [from what I've read](http://askville.amazon.com/default-user-php-script-run-linux/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=7355802), changing Apache will fix that, since PHP is spawned by Apache.

Comment: Note: technically, php isn't (usually) spawned by Apache, instead php runs inside Apache.

Comment: What does it mean to run "inside" Apache? Do you know of any resources about this sort of thing I could look at? It's hard to find anything concrete about how Apache and PHP work together.

Comment: PHP, normally, [is already in apache](http://notehub.org/2014/7/20/apache-is-a-fairly-complex-app-there-are).